# Error opening the IExpress Self Extraction Directive file

Tags: c#, exe, iexpress

So I tried to make a program in C# that connects two .exe files by `IExpress` command but it throws an error in the title of the thread.

Code that seems to not work:

```cs
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@$"{workdir}\script.sed"));
sw.Write($"[Version] \nClass=IEXPRESS \nSEDVersion=3 \n[Options] \nPackagePurpose=InstallApp \nShowInstallProgramWindow=0 \nHideExtractAnimation=1 \nUseLongFileName=1 \nInsideCompressed=0 \nCAB_FixedSize=0 \nCAB_ResvCodeSigning=0 \nRebootMode=I \nInstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt% \nDisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense% \nFinishMessage=%FinishMessage% \nTargetName=%TargetName% \nFriendlyName=%FriendlyName% \nAppLaunched=%AppLaunched% \nPostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd% \nAdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd% \nUserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd% \nSourceFiles=SourceFiles \n[Strings] \nInstallPrompt= \nDisplayLicense= \nFinishMessage= \nTargetName={Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}+wpkg2.exe \nFriendlyName=All your SEDs are belong to us \nAppLaunched={Path.GetFileName(file)}\nAppLaunched2=wpkg2.exe\nPostInstallCmd=<None> \nAdminQuietInstCmd= \nUserQuietInstCmd= \nFILE0=wpkg2.exe\nFILE1={Path.GetFileName(file)}\n[SourceFiles]\nSourceFiles0={Path.GetDirectoryName(file)}\nSourceFiles1={workdir}\n[SourceFiles0]\n%FILE1%=\n[SourceFiles1]\n%FILE0%=");
sw.Close();

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\iexpress.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @$"/N {workdir}\script.sed";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
//startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
//startInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
```

I tried to execute the command as administrator but it did not work too. (The code that is commented is the code I tried to use to execute command as administrator)

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you run `IExpress.exe` from the command line using the `/N` option, it will display that error if the **path** to the SED file contains spaces.  It will display the error whether or not you surround the file path in quotes.  I'm only aware of two workarounds:

1. Make sure you name your SED file, and the folders that contain it, don't contain spaces in their names
2. Run IExpress *without* the /N option and specify the SED file path via its wizard UI (in which case spaces are allowed)